# How to use Python to download whole section from a website

Tags: python, file, http, download

I've found some pretty good snippets to download files from web, but it could download just one file. How am I able to download a whole directory, after one call, from some site ?

Eg.: If some site have all the files that I want located in one directory, how could I say ?

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.website.com/files/*.*", "*.*")
```

Comment: You must extract urls from that website first, then use whichever method you like. `scrapy` is a good tool to extract urls.

Comment: you have to use `urllib` to download page (`HTML`) and then you use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to find links in `HTML` and then use `urlretrieve` with every link separately.

Comment: @NarūnasK What if in my site does not have a link, not even a page, just directories ?

Comment: If you own the site you have to work out a way to expose valid urls, then use these urls to retrieve the content you want. For instance `http://www.website.com/files/index.html` may contain file lists. You cannot use wild cards in urls, this is not how the web works.

Comment: @NarūnasK Thanks !